# Recover dropped mysql sys schema

Tags: mysql, schema, recovery

I dropped the sys schema while tinkering around mysql 8(current version). Is there a way to recover it. I am using ubuntu 20.04. I tried using the mysql documentation but I couldn't find anything relevant. Could someone with better experience help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO offers help on database admin questions like this one.

Comment: SQL for those is [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/tree/8.0/scripts/sys_schema/views) however I hope someone can offer a better recommendation. If you have another server you could take a mysqldump of the `sys` schema and import that into your current version.

Comment: *Is there a way to recover it.* If you have no complete schema backup then noway.

Comment: `sys` schema is just inbuilt views.

Comment: I saw an available sys schema on [github](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys) but it is meant for 5.6 or 5.7. can I get for mysql 8.0?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the folder of the [github
   repo](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/tree/8.0/scripts/sys_schema).
2. Download the sys_schema folder using
   [gitzip](http://kinolien.github.io/gitzip/) or any other available
   extensions. I personally used gitzip. Needless to say you can
   download the whole [mysql-server repo](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server) but that would be inefficient
   as you do not need everything and it has a heavy download size.
3. Extract it to a folder and **cd** into it
4. Log in to the mysql client

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   ```
5. Import the sys_57.sql file. Don't mind the name, it is compatible
   with mysql 8. using

   ```
   source ./sys_57.sql
   ```

There you go, you have your sys schema back. Thanks to [danblack](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/158002/danblack) for giving me a cue.

> P.S [akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina) this is
> computer, there is always a way